# Print Universal Characters (html) stored in a string c++

Tags: html, c++, unicode-string

I am trying to print a string with universal characters stored in it. If i initialized the string with the following:

```
string test = "\u000D\u000A\u000D\u000Aclass Solution {\u000D\u000Apublic:\u000D\u000A 
cout << test << endl;
```

it would print out the output I want:

```
class Solution {
```

but if I get the same string from Curl result, like following:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, addressof(test));
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
cout << test << endl;
```

it would print out:

```
\u000D\u000A\u000D\u000Aclass Solution {\u000D\u000Apublic:\u000D\u000A
```

I tried to turn the test into const char * by c_str and then print it out, but it is still not working. I tried to google it for a few hours but unfortunately I cannot find the answer.
I am using Mac and compile with

```
clang++ -std=c++11  -Wall -Wextra -lcurl
```

May anyone help me on this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Universal characters are a concept known to the C++ compiler, not translated at runtime.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of codesets, encodings, locales, and Unicode. You will find a few thousand pages' worth of reference material down the hall, last door on your left. The infinitessimal chance of an answer is only possible after determining one's host O/S and system environment configuration; and since that info wasn't given in the question no authoritative answer will be possible.

Comment: @chris Thanks for your answer, is any possible way that I could fix the problem?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hi Sam, thank you for your answer. My O/S is OS X. I am sorry that I am new in cs. May you teach me how may I get the system environment configuration? And if there is any possible way to solve my problem? Thanks

Comment: @YifeiWang, If you're getting these escape sequences and you need them converted, you're not going to be able to avoid replicating some of the compiler's work in some way, including a library. As Sam said, the translated bytes also need to be encoded according to your desired scheme (e.g., UTF-8). This may or may not be mostly avoidable depending on the range of code points that need to be supported.

Comment: @chris Thank you for your reply. I will do some more readings about escape sequences and UTF-8 and see if I could figure it out by myself. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone facing the same issue, I get this done by using ICU library with UnicodeString Converter.